# postgresql seq scan sometimes very slow. restart of postgres solves it for a while

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have having a problem where the same query on a table sometimes takes several seconds and most times completes in a few milliseconds. Restart of Postgres seems to resolve the issue and keep it away for a couple of days.

- Table - alarm
- 20 clients reading from the table.
- 1 client making several inserts and udpates every second. Delete/purge is a nightly cron.
- Plenty of RAM still available, only 20% of CPU on the host being used.

After the above conditions persist for a while, the query starts taking 5+ seconds to complete.

Just restart of the clients and Postgres solves this by bring it down to few milliseconds.

`explain analyze` shows a sequential scan on this table both the times. But it is in the order of milliseconds when Postgres is just started and later it increases to a few seconds.

There are about 25000 records in this table.

Any suggestions, ideas on how to debug when the seq scan is slow? Could it be fragmentation in the shared_buffer or locking of the table causing this. I doubt it is a disk or IO issue because they should cause a problem irrespective of when Postgres is started.

At the time of the issue, I missed using buffers in analyze. The output is like below:

```
    explain analyze SELECT s.severity, s.severityid from SEVERITY s where s.severityid =(select MIN(severityid) from  ALARM a, (SELECT * FROM RESOURCEDETAILS) as  RESOURCEDETAILS  WHERE RESOURCEDETAILS.resourcegroupid = 132 AND RESOURCEDETAILS.resourceid = a.resourceid AND a.severityid  1 AND a.severityid  2 AND a.severityid  7);
                                                                             QUERY PLAN
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Seq Scan on severity s  (cost=4701.39..4702.47 rows=1 width=13) (actual time=7057.939..7057.940 rows=1 loops=1)
       Filter: (severityid = $0)
       Rows Removed by Filter: 6
       InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
         ->  Aggregate  (cost=4701.38..4701.39 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=7057.918..7057.918 rows=1 loops=1)
               ->  Hash Join  (cost=533.69..4701.25 rows=51 width=8) (actual time=1849.630..7057.783 rows=223 loops=1)
                     Hash Cond: (a.resourceid = resourcedetails.resourceid)
                     ->  Seq Scan on alarm a  (cost=0.00..4157.70 rows=2491 width=16) (actual time=45.792..6608.120 rows=852 loops=1)
                           Filter: ((severityid  1) AND (severityid  2) AND (severityid  7))
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 24376
                     ->  Hash  (cost=528.27..528.27 rows=434 width=8) (actual time=448.540..448.540 rows=19 loops=1)
                           Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
                           ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on resourcedetails  (cost=7.65..528.27 rows=434 width=8) (actual time=0.128..448.495 rows=19 loops=1)
                                 Recheck Cond: (resourcegroupid = 132)
                                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on resourcedetails_rg_idx  (cost=0.00..7.54 rows=434 width=0) (actual time=0.103..0.103 rows=63 loops=1)
                                       Index Cond: (resourcegroupid = 132)
    Total runtime: 7058.156 ms
    (17 rows)
```

```
After postgres restart, the problem was resolved and here is the output:
(This time with all options of explain)
                                                                             <pre>
explain (analyze,buffers,costs,timing,verbose) SELECT s.severity, s.severityid from SEVERITY s where s.severityid =(select MIN(severityid) from  ALARM a, (SELECT * FROM RESOURCEDETAILS) as  RESOURCEDETAILS  WHERE RESOURCEDETAILS.resourcegroupid = 132 AND RESOURCEDETAILS.resourceid = a.resourceid AND a.severityid <> 1 AND a.severityid <> 2 AND a.severityid <> 7);
                                                                                                                       QUERY PLAN

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on public.severity s  (cost=4516.93..4518.02 rows=1 width=13) (actual time=15.881..15.882 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: s.severity, s.severityid
   Filter: (s.severityid = $0)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 6
   Buffers: shared hit=3167
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Aggregate  (cost=4516.92..4516.93 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=15.874..15.875 rows=1 loops=1)
           Output: min(a.severityid)
           Buffers: shared hit=3166
           ->  Hash Join  (cost=520.61..4516.91 rows=5 width=8) (actual time=7.043..15.869 rows=2 loops=1)
                 Output: a.severityid
                 Hash Cond: (a.resourceid = resourcedetails.resourceid)
                 Buffers: shared hit=3166
                 ->  Seq Scan on public.alarm a  (cost=0.00..3995.37 rows=232 width=16) (actual time=0.142..15.492 rows=108 loops=1)
                       Output: a.alarmid, a.eventtypeid, a.severityid, a.source, a.resourceid, a.componentid, a.category, a.createdtime, a.updatedtime, a.owner, a.ackstatus, a.acktime, a.clearedtime, a.messa
ge, a.remedy, a.optionalfield, a.version
                       Filter: ((a.severityid <> 1) AND (a.severityid <> 2) AND (a.severityid <> 7))
                       Rows Removed by Filter: 26130
                       Buffers: shared hit=3108
                 ->  Hash  (cost=515.39..515.39 rows=418 width=8) (actual time=0.338..0.338 rows=19 loops=1)
                       Output: resourcedetails.resourceid
                       Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
                       Buffers: shared hit=58
                       ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.resourcedetails  (cost=7.53..515.39 rows=418 width=8) (actual time=0.033..0.330 rows=19 loops=1)
                             Output: resourcedetails.resourceid
                             Recheck Cond: (resourcedetails.resourcegroupid = 132)
                             Buffers: shared hit=58
                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on resourcedetails_rg_idx  (cost=0.00..7.42 rows=418 width=0) (actual time=0.023..0.023 rows=61 loops=1)
                                   Index Cond: (resourcedetails.resourcegroupid = 132)
                                   Buffers: shared hit=3
 Total runtime: 15.937 ms
(30 rows)
```

After postgresql restart, the query seems to deteriorate steadily...

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Comment: [edit] your question and add the output of `explain (analyze, verbose, buffers)` for the fast and slow execution of the statement (_formatted_ text please, [no screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557))

Comment: Is autovacuum running when you experience the slow down?

Comment: We have about 1000+ tables... so autovacuum is running for some table all the time... not for this table at the time we see the slowness... once the slowness starts... it remains slow till postgres is restarted..